# Move ur10 with ROS topic

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, ur10, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, with my project I'm trying to move the ur10 robot and I've attached a 3-finger gripper at the end-effector. I've already found some documentation on how to move it giving values to the joints, however my goal would be to give a final pose of the end-effector and make it unfold in order to get to that pose.

My thought would be of using the inverse kinematics and as you can imagine it's quite complex and I can't find it. I'm trying to simulate the robot in gazebo so I can see it moving, so I would need a way of setting a final pose for the end effector and with this calculate the joints positions or simply make it move to there.

I'd appreciate some feedback.

EDIT 1: The link provided by @lagankapoor doesn't help much for what I'm trying to do. I've created the package of my robot for moveit and made it move there by moving the end effector and clicking "Plan and Execute". However I need the robot to move while having a node publishing the end-effector pose inside a loop. For example, in pseudo code:

```
while (ros::ok())
    x,y,z = pose of end effector
    make robot unfold so end effector reaches x,y,z
```

something like this is what I want to do if possible

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281791/move-ur10-with-ros-topic/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-05**:
You want a repo or want to hind for that ?

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-05**:
@lagankapoor Sorry but what do you mean?
I've managed to attach a gripper to the ur10 and I can open/close the gripper but also want to move the arm. What would be my options?

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-05**:
you have two option you can use moveIt for planning and otherwise you can use GUI in Rviz like Joint publisher

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-05**:
@lagankapoor  Using a GUI in Rviz is not viable for me as I'm interested to feed the pose of the end-effector, not the joints. Can you explain me in a few words hoe the planning in moveit works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i think this link will help you please [checkit](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial)

here you have github repo from UR [visit](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot)  this one

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-05**:
@lagankapoor the link you provided doesn't help much. I've created a package  with moveit assistant setup and I can move the end effector and then press "Plan and execute". But what I need is to give the end effector pose within a script and make it execute the path to get there

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-05**:
@Juantelo then try to use kinematics with your scripts because that's the way for pos